# SPARQL subquery in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to filter a resource that is used as "join" in the query. 
For example, given a DBpedia resource, i need to return the label of resources linked by sameAs property and has "pt" in its URI. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT ?label
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Algorithms> owl:sameAs ?nomePT.
   ?nomePT rdfs:label ?label
    FILTER regex(str(?nomePT), "pt", "i") 
}
```

However, it returns empty because the variable "?NomePT" always contains the first resource from the list. see:

```
SELECT ?nomePT
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Algorithms> owl:sameAs ?nomePT.
   ?nomePT rdfs:label ?label
}
```

But the resource has several sameAs links:

```
SELECT ?nomePT
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Algorithms> owl:sameAs ?nomePT.}
```

what's wrong in the query?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the query:

```
SELECT distinct * {
    ?nomePT owl:sameAs category:Algorithms.
}
```

You will get all links that are `owl:sameAs` your resource `category:Algorithms`. However, you are already limiting the scope of the triple. So if you ask for:

```
SELECT distinct ?nomePT {
    ?nomePT owl:sameAs category:Algorithms.
    ?nomePT rdfs:label ?label
}
```

[image]

If first finds your specific resource and then looks for the label only for that resource. However, if you don't bound your triple at the start and only filter your resource will give you all links you need:

```
SELECT distinct ?resource {
    ?nomePT owl:sameAs ?resource.
    ?nomePT rdfs:label ?label.
filter( ?nomePT=category:Algorithms )
}
```

[image]

Thus you should first find all the resources and then filter them based on a specific resource such as `category:Algorithms` and since sameAs is reflexive:

```
SELECT distinct * {
    ?nomePT owl:sameAs ?resource.
    ?nomePT rdfs:label ?label.
filter( ?nomePT=category:Algorithms && regex(str(?resource), "pt", "i") )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `filter( *?resource*=category:Algorithms && ...`

Comment: Engines may optimize `FILTER(?resource=category:Algorithms)` and its used in a longer `&&` expression, to do the same as `?resource owl:sameAs category:Algorithms` as well as returning `?resource= category:Algorithms` in the answers.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Not sure what you want elaboratinbg : `SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o . FILTER (?s=<uri>) }` can be optimized to `SELECT * { <uri> ?p ?o . BIND(<uri> AS ?s)  }`

Comment: In fact, I wanted to recover the label in Portuguese, but this is impossible because the'm doing the query in the English edition and in this edition the only thing that will find is the sameAs. So I need to do two queries in one edition in English (dbpedia.org/sparql) to retrieve my uri in Portuguese and another in Portuguese edition (pt.dbpedia.org/sparql) to retrieve the label in Portuguese.
Thanks for your help.